# Crystal Report graph and font squashed in PDF preview

Tags: graph, crystal-reports

When I export my CR report in PDF version my graph and font as well look odd, actually they look kind of squashed. In the CR designer everything looks fine in the preview. Here is the image of two subreports, graph and the cross tab under exported in PDF and the difference is obvious. Does anyone have a clue why is this happening?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to print using a PDF printer such as PDFCreator or CutePDF? Does the PDF look the same using an alternative way to create the PDF?

Comment: @SunWKim I tested today the report with external PDF generators and I got a good PDF. Thanks for that. So, I have a problem generating it via code... But only generating the chars.

Comment: I exported some charts and crosstabs as a PDF from the Crystal Reports XI Release 2 application. I also tried crexport and nothing is getting squished on my end... http://www.rainforestnet.com/crystal-reports-exporter/  Good luck. I am not a programmer, so I am not familiar with creating the PDF from code.

Comment: @SunWKim There is no big deal exporting it through code, there is only one line which do that and as far as I know there are no any kind of settings I can apply before that. Thanks for your reply again.